# How to add window service exe (as external exe) in clickonce

Tags: c#, wpf, service, clickonce, desktop-application

i have a solution that having the desktop ui wpf project and a window service. I need to create clickonce installer. I have successfully created the installer for wpf application. For window service i just added the **reference of project into wpf project**. Including the window service exe in application files and then publish the application. I got following error message while installation of clickonce setup

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO     Windows             : 10.0.18363.0 (Win32NT)    Common
> Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.42000   System.Deployment.dll       :
> 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1    clr.dll             : 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C  dfdll.dll           : 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
> dfshim.dll          : 10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
>
> SOURCES   Deployment url          :
> http://192.168.0.162:8189/Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop.application
> Server      : Microsoft-IIS/10.0
> X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET   Deployment Provider url     : http://192.168.0.162:8189/Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop.application
> Application url         :
> http://192.168.0.162:8189/Application%20Files/Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop_1_0_0_53/Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop.exe.manifest
> Server      : Microsoft-IIS/10.0
> X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
>
> IDENTITIES    Deployment Identity     :
> Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop.application, Version=1.0.0.53,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd5358bf47526dee,
> processorArchitecture=msil    Application Identity        :
> Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop.exe, Version=1.0.0.53,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd5358bf47526dee,
> processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY   * Installable application.
>
> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
> errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of
> http://192.168.0.162:8189/Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop.application
> resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:      +
> Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the
> downloaded assembly Netsolace.Edible.Partner.WindowServices.exe.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
> detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS     * [10/21/2020 12:47:03 PM] : Activation of
> http://192.168.0.162:8189/Netsolace.Edible.Partner.Desktop.application
> has started.  * [10/21/2020 12:47:03 PM] : Processing of deployment
> manifest has successfully completed.  * [10/21/2020 12:47:03 PM] :
> Installation of the application has started.  * [10/21/2020 12:47:04
> PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
>
> - [10/21/2020 12:47:06 PM] : Found compatible runtime version
>   4.0.30319.    * [10/21/2020 12:47:06 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>
> - [10/21/2020 12:47:08 PM]
>   System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException
>   (RefDefValidation)
>
>   - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Netsolace.Edible.Partner.WindowServices.exe.
>   - Source: System.Deployment
>   - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object
>     sender, DownloadEventArgs e)          at
>     System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>     sender, DownloadEventArgs e)          at
>     System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()             at
>     System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>     next)             at
>     System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>     at
>     System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>     subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)             at
>     System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState
>     subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest
>     appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group,
>     IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)          at
>     System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>     subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>     TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at
>     System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>     subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          at
>     System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>     activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>     deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>     String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)             at
>     System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>     activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>     deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>     String& errorPageUrl)
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---          at
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()            at
>     System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>     activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>     deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>     String& errorPageUrl)             at
>     System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>     state)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
> available.

Comment: ClickOnce was not designed for installing Windows Services.  Consider using regular installer technologies

Comment: i knew, i am adding window service just like external exe

Comment: ClickOnce is for deploying WinForms and WPF-style apps on a _per-user_ basis.  Apps are installed to C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\xxx\xxx

Answer (score -1):

You can add that exe in your current solution using
**Add->Add Existing Files** (All files).

If that exe still not produce in ClickOnce setup, then check properties of that added
exe by pressing **F4 key** .

Hope this answer helpful.

Comment: I have done same things are getting above error after installation

Comment: what is the Build Action property of ur EXE

Comment: You might be able to deploy additional .EXEs that way but it won't register the Windows Service nor allow for uninstallation of the WS later via **Add/Remove Programs**

Comment: instead of using ClickOnce try Wix. It is open source and easy to use tool for deployment.